# Show "Rate My App" alert when user clicked on exit (before exiting from app)

Tags: android

I have implemented "Rate My Application" Functionality. But I want to show alert to ask rating only when user clicked on `exit` Button.

Code for AppRater is from http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-engaged-users-to-rate-your-app-in-the-android-market-appirater

code on exit button:

```
case R.id.exit:
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Exiting from application");
        AppRater.app_launched(this);   //Display alert for app rating
        Intent exitIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        exitIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        exitIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(exitIntent);
        this.finish();
        break;
```

Now with this code, it shows alert just for a second, as the current activity get finished.

I want to finish the current activity only when user will click any button from alert box.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the activity for result....
instead of startActivity() method u can use startActivityForResult()... may be this work...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Calling this.finish() immediately after you show the dialog box.

Call the same after any of the button is selected in the DialogBox shown.

As you are calling this.finish() the context is lost immediately so closing the dialog as well.

If you do this you do not need to have the below code in your app.

```
    Intent exitIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    exitIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    exitIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(exitIntent);
    this.finish();
```